# How to get count of pipe objects? I don't want accumulate pipe to buffer

Tags: powershell, count, pipe

Assume I have some powershell code:

```
function count-pipe {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
        [object[]]$inputObject
    )

    process {
        $PipeCount = <# How to get count of the pipe? Expect: #> 5

        Write-Output $inputObject # path-throw
    }
}

1..5 | count-pipe | % { $_ }
```

Yes, I can sum/measure count to temp-variable and use the tee cmdlet. I think this solution make pause the pipe. I think also the temp-valiable is not a good solution relate a memory consumption.

Can I get a pipe objects count without accumulate to temp-variable?

Thanks.

Comment: How do you intend to use `$PipeCount`, and why isn't `$PipeCount++` a solution?

Comment: The point of the pipe is there will be only one object in there at a time so to speak. You are trying to predict the future then? not sure how you would do this without a temp variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think using a counter variable is the solution I would use:

```
function count-pipe {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
        [object[]]$InputObject
    )
    Process {
        $PipeCount++
        $_
    }
    End {
        Write-Verbose $PipeCount
    }

}

'a','b' | count-pipe -verbose | % { $_ }
```

Comment: @Mark Wragg, thanks. Your code get pipe count after pipe complete.


Question is: how to get pipe.count inside process? )))

Comment: @gms0ulman, yes. this comment was to previous version answer.


With this version pipe.count takes correct value ater cmdlet run )))
Question is: how to get pipe.count inside process?

Comment: How to get pipe count inside `process`? You don't, because the `process` block runs once for each item as each item "arrives" in the pipeline. To count the items, either collect them all beforehand and iterate the collection (like the `foreach` statement) or use a counter (like in this answer).

Answer (score 1):

### Found alternate answer:

Using [`Measure-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/measure-object?view=powershell-7#example-8--measure-all-the-values)

Powershell:

```bsh
@(1,2,3) | Measure-Object
```

Output:

```sh
Count    : 3
Average  :
Sum      :
Maximum  :
Minimum  :
Property :
```

Powershell:

```bsh
1..5 | Measure-Object -AllStats
```

Output:

```sh
Count             : 5
Average           : 3
Sum               : 15
Maximum           : 5
Minimum           : 1
StandardDeviation : 1.58113883008419
Property          :
```

---

### For this use case:

Powershell:

```bsh
$listMeasure = $list | Measure-Object
$listCount = $listMeasure.Count
```

---

Examples from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pipelines?view=powershell-7#one-at-a-time-processing) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/measure-object?view=powershell-7#example-8--measure-all-the-values)