# PowerShell: How to get count of piped collection?

Tags: powershell, count, size

Suppose I have a process that generates a collection of objects. For a very simple example, consider `$(1 | get-member)`. I can get the number of objects generated:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $(1 | get-member).count
21
```

or I can do something with those objects.

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $(1 | get-member) | ForEach-object {write-host $_.name}
CompareTo
Equals
...
```

With only 21 objects, doing the above is no problem. But what if the process generates hundreds of thousands of objects? Then I don't want to run the process once just to count the objects and then run it again to execute what I want to do with them. So how can I get a count of objects in a collection sent down the pipeline?

A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45565980/how-to-get-count-of-pipe-objects-i-dont-want-accumulate-pipe-to-buffer) was asked before, and the accepted answer was to use a counter variable inside the script block that works on the collection. The problem is that I already have that counter and what I want is to check that the outcome of that counter is correct. So I don't want to just count inside the script block. I want a separate, independent measure of the size of the collection that I sent down the pipeline. How can I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**If processing *and* counting is needed:**

Doing your own counting inside a `ForEach-Object` script block is your best bet to avoid processing in two passes.

> The problem is that I already have that counter and what I want is to check that the outcome of that counter is correct.

`ForEach-Object` is reliably invoked for each and every input object, including `$null` values, so there should be no need to double-check.

If you want a cleaner *separation* of processing and counting, you can pass *multiple* `-Process` script blocks to `ForEach-Object` (in this example, `{ $_ + 1 }` is the input-*processing* script block and `{ ++$count }` is the input-*counting* one):

```sh
PS> 1..5 | ForEach-Object -Begin { $count = 0 } `
                          -Process { $_ + 1 }, { ++$count } `
                          -End { "--- count: $count" }

2
3
4
5
6
--- count: 5
```

Note that, due to a quirk in `ForEach-Object`'s parameter binding, passing `-Begin` and `-End` script blocks is actually *required* in order to pass multiple `-Process` (per-input-object) blocks; pass `$null` if you don't actually need `-Begin` and/or `-End` - see [GitHub issue #4513](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/4513#issuecomment-546625189).

Also note that the `$count` variable lives in the caller's scope, and is not scoped to the `ForEach-Object` call; that is, `$count = 0` potentially updates a preexisting `$count` variable, and, if it didn't previously exist, lives on after the `ForEach-Object` call.

---

**If *only* counting is needed:**

[`Measure-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/measure-object) is the cmdlet to use with *large, streaming input collections* in the pipeline<sup>[1]</sup>:

The following example generates 100,000 integers one by one and has `Measure-Object` count them one by one, without collecting the entire input in memory.

```sh
PS> (& { $i=0; while ($i -lt 1e5) { (++$i) } } | Measure-Object).Count
100000
```

**Caveat**: `Measure-Object` ignores `$null` values in the input collection - see [GitHub issue #10905](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10905).

Note that while *counting* input objects is `Measure-Object`'s default behavior, it supports a variety of other operations as well, such as *summing* `-Sum` and *averaging* (`-Average`), optionally combined in a single invocation.

---

<sup>[1] `Measure-Object`, as a *cmdlet*, is capable of processing input in a *streaming* fashion, meaning it counts objects it receives *one by one*, as they're being received, which means that even very large streaming input sets (those also created one by one, such as enumerating the rows of a large CSV file with `Import-Csv`) can be processed without the risk of running out of memory - there is no need to load the input collection *as a whole* into memory. However, if (a) the input collection already *is* in memory, or (b) it *can fit* into memory and performance is important, then use `(...).Count`.</sup>

Comment: 1) You say no reason to check because `ForEach-object` is reliably invoked. But the need for checking is because of potential error in my script block. So I think I see now that because of how piping works, if I need to run process B on output of process A and check process B for such errors, then I do need to (a) save output of process A to an array and get size of array, (b) separately pipe output of process A to process B with counter in process B, and (c) compare size from (a) with counter from (b). This requires running A twice, but that's the cost of error checking. Does that make sense?

Comment: 2) You say to use `measure-object`. But why do that instead of just `count`? in other words, why do `($array | measure-object).count` when you can just do `$array.count`?

Comment: @NewSites: Re 2) `Measure-Object`, as a _cmdlet_, is capable of processing input in a _streaming_ fashion, meaning it counts objects _one by one_, as they're being received, which means that even very large input sets - also created one by one, such as enumerating the rows of a large CSV file with `Import-Csv` - can be processed without the risk of running out of memory - there is no need to load the input collection _as a whole_ into memory. If (a) the input collection already _is_ in memory, or (b) it _can fit_ into memory and performance is important, then do use `.Count`.

Comment: Re 1) I'm not sure I fully understand, but note that you can perform error handling inside of `ForEach-Object` script blocks. That is, you can detect / catch / ignore errors as needed and perform conditional counting.

Comment: I found that try-catch does not always catch all errors! See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58558585/powershell-try-catch-loses-repeated-access-errors . So I'm treading carefully and checking my results. But now I wonder if I can take what your answer said about passing multiple `process` blocks and what your comment said about `measure-object` working in streaming fashion, and combining that to do a count of the output of process A in parallel with but independent from the count taking place in process B. Should that work as an alternative to saving the array from A and measuring it?

Comment: No, I don't think what I asked about in my previous comment is sufficient. To do the check I need, it needs to be done on the result of process A as a whole, outside the pipeline.